# Check which HTA file is running

Tags: c#, hta

I am integrating with some thirdparty software that runs with an .hta file inside of mshta.exe. My app is written in C#

I need to detect if the .hta file is already running so I can launch it before I start sending messages to it.

With past integrations with other third parties, I have checked for the exe in the process list, but I don't think that I can just look for mshta.exe because they could be running some other .hta file.

I also tried grabbing the `process.MainWindowTitle` from `Process.GetProcesses()`, but even though the mshta.exe window is showing a title, the `MainWindowTitle` property is blank.

Does anyone know a method where I could figure out that mshta.exe is running a specific hta file?

Comment: Check the command line of each mshta.exe, it should contain the path of the running hta.

Comment: Can you post the source code of your HTA ?

Comment: Unfortunately, its a 3rd party HTA file so I can't share it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Teemu's comment, I found that the `.hta` path is indeed in the command line arguments. However, this information is not in the `Process` reference (even though there is an `Arguments` property on the process's `StartInfo`). You have to use the `ManagementObjectSearcher` like so:

```
//Call this extension on the mshta.exe process to get the path of the .hta file
public static string GetCommandLine(this Process process) {
    var commandLine = new StringBuilder(process.MainModule.FileName);

    commandLine.Append(" ");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT CommandLine FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + process.Id)) {
        foreach (var commandLinePart in searcher.Get()) {
            commandLine.Append(commandLinePart["CommandLine"]);
            commandLine.Append(" ");
        }
    }

    return commandLine.ToString();
}
```